# In fluorescence, if you excite a fluorophore with 2 wavelengths (one closer to the resonance wavelength than the other) will the emission change?

Tags: photons, fluorescence

Say my fluorophore's resonance wavelength is 500nm. I excite the fluorophore with equal energies of 500nm and 550nm. The 550nm light excites the fluorophore, but is inherently weaker than 500nm excitation as the resonant wavelength is 500nm for this material. Say the emission intensity of 550nm is a value of x. If we excite at both 550 and 500nm simultaneously, will the emission band from 550nm be less than x or equal to x?